# handling issue with listbox in a pivot

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm working on a app in which I used a listbox inside a pivot control just like the outlook app does. The problem is sometimes when I scroll the list, a swipe gesture is triggered and it goes to another pivot item. This is very annoying, and it seems doesn't happen to the outlook app. Am I doing something wrong? How do I fix it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just using the default controls in the default way then you're not doing anything wrong in your code.

You haven't said if you're getting this on the emualtor or on an actual device. I find I sometimes do this on the emulator if holding the mouse at a slight angle or on an actual device if holding that in a funny way (such as when lying down).

Whether you scroll the listbox or the pivot will depend on whether your finger (or mouse-if using the emulator on a non touch-screen PC) first moves vertically or horizontally after first touching the screen. In my experience the scenarios described above can lead to this not always working as expected but I've never seen an issue with this on a real device being held in one hand and scrolled using a thumb.

Comment: I was testing it on my device(HD7). Thanks for you reply but I can't agree with what you said that "Whether you scroll the listbox or the pivot will depend on whether your finger first moves...". Because if I move my finger to a corner, it'll scroll both vertically and horizontally! This is why I'm sure something is wrong with my App, it doesn't happen to outlook.

Comment: I've tried on a couple of different LG devices but it only happens on one. I suspect that it is due to the screen on a particular device and where it can detect touches. My guess is that when you go right in to the corner (or a bit to far over one of the edges) it loses reference to the UIElement being touched and when you move your finger back over the control it starts a new manipulation-in a different direction. As this doesn't happen in Outlook this may just be a Silverlight related issue (the native apps aren't written in Silverlight).

Comment: I suspect that as users become familiar with their devices they will learn the nuances of gesture detection in their particular model. If you are really concerned about this check against other non-native apps on the device to see if they suffer the same issue. (This is how I tested.)

Comment: you are right about the other non-native apps, e.g. twitter has the same issue. but I won't be happy unless this happens to native apps too.

Comment: But it's good to know that native apps are not written in Silverlight, and I did nothing wrong :)